# How to get a list of mounted sub applications from a FastAPI app?

Tags: python, fastapi, starlette

I have a FastAPI app with a few mounted [sub applications](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/sub-applications/), and would like to know if there is a `app.subapps()` or similar method to give me the instances of sub applications mounted to the main app.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every app that is mounted into another application is [added to the application's routes as a mounted route](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/3df3df1d79b2226c2ba6bea344f08afc1673b6ed/starlette/routing.py#L812).

We can therefor iterate over the registered routes and keep those that are [instances of the `Mount` object](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/3df3df1d79b2226c2ba6bea344f08afc1673b6ed/starlette/routing.py#L386).

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from starlette.routing import Mount

app = FastAPI()
app2 = FastAPI()

@app2.get("/")
def app2ish():
    return {"version": "app2"}

app.mount("/app2", app2)


@app.get("/")
async def app1ish():
    return {"version": "app"}

    

def get_mounted_apps(app):
    return [
        route.app
        for route in app.router.routes
        if isinstance(route, Mount)
    ]

    
print(get_mounted_apps(app))
```

This outputs:

```
[<fastapi.applications.FastAPI object at 0x00000224FFDEFC70>]
```

Comment: I also went through the source code to see whether FastAPI (actually, Starlette) keeps track of the mounted apps, which would easily allow one to get all of them. It is very unfortunate that Starlette does not maintain such a list, and thus, one has to loop through every route (which could be hundreds), in order to get a list of the mounted apps. Not to mention that one should further filter that returned list of objects, as other apps, such as `StaticFiles`, might also be part of it (e.g., `<starlette.staticfiles.StaticFiles object at ...>`).

Comment: Thank you both, this was incredibly helpful and just what I was looking for. @MatsLindh I'd suggest for anyone else reading your answer in the future adding a list(set()) to your list comprehension to give a list of distinct apps.

And good point Chris, StaticFiles mounts should also be filtered out